# Display The Reversing of the string in the applet

Tags: java, applet

I am new to Java Programming.I need to write an applet to display reversing of a string.I should show as each character is flying and arranging in a reverse order.Could anybody guide me how to do so. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Break your problem (homework?) into steps:

- Do you know how to make an applet? If no, search on "java applet tutorial"
- Do you know how to display a text? If no, look at the JLabel documentation
- Do you know how to change things over time? If no, look at the javax.swing.Timer documentation (note there are multiple classes named Timer, get the Swing one)
- Do want to get fancy animations? If yes, search on "java custom painting tutorial" (or perhaps look into JavaFX which should make animations easier)

Comment: Hi Walter, i know the above mentioned topics.

Comment: my problem is i need to show each character in the string as flying, for example,. if I type Hello in the textfield, the orginal string should be printed first(this part I have done) then each character should be taken and to be printed in reverse as "olleH" .

Answer (score 1):

```
     import javax.swing.*;
     import java.awt.BorderLayout;
     import java.awt.event.*;

     public class ShowReverse extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
     private JLabel reverseLabel;
     private JTextField inputField;
      private JButton clickButton;

      // Kicks off applet
      public void init() {
      reverseLabel = new JLabel();
     inputField = new JTextField();
      clickButton = new JButton("Reverse");

     // Add event listener to button
      clickButton.addActionListener(this);

     // Add the input field at the top, label in the middle and button at bottom
      add(inputField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(reverseLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       add(clickButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }


       // When button is clicked, it performs this action.
       // Set the label to the result of our reverse function.
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if (e.getSource() == clickButton) {
         reverseLabel.setText( reverse(inputField.getText() ));

           }
       }


      // reverses a string by simply looping through the characters backwards
        // and builds the string.
          private String reverse(String text) {
             if (text.length() > 1) {
               String reversed = "";

                for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
               reversed += Character.toString(text.charAt(i));
               }

            return reversed;

           }
           else { return text; }

         }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need flying characters, you should use Graphics instead of just text.
You represent each letter as image or set of figures and then swap due to reversing algorithm.

But, first of all you need to understand how to draw in applet. Hope this article helps http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Graphics-in-a-Java-Applet

Answer (score 0):

The String class can not have a Reverse method becuase it is immutable . so we can use StringBuffer for revese a given String.here we can reverse the given input of t1(TextField) into the t2(TextField).but textfield method  setText(String) is accept one argument that must be in a String then we can use the toString() method to convert the StringBuffer value into String value.

Show this example:

```
    import java.awt.*;

    import java.applet.Applet;

    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class rev extends Applet implements ActionListener

    {

    Button b;
    TextField t,t1;

    public void init()
    {
        b=new Button("Reverse");

        Label l=new Label("enter a your Name");
        add(l);
        t=new TextField(" ",15);
        add(t);
        Label l1=new Label("The reverce ");
        add(l1);
        t1=new TextField(" ",15);
        add(t1);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        add(b);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String sa=t.getText();
        StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer(sa);
        t1.setText(t.getText()+"  "+a.reverse().toString());

    }
   }
```